# Cakephp 3.0 Sql Injection Protection

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, sql-injection

how to protect my code of Cakephp 3.0 against sql injection. Cook book just give me the idea that we should use column name or user data directly but dont know how to do it??

Answer (score 3):

Not entirely true @doonot: You can expose yourself, if you're using some of the more "advanced" parts of the ORM:

> While the ORM and database abstraction layers prevent most SQL injections issues, it is still possible to leave yourself vulnerable through improper use. When using the expression builder, column names must not contain user data:

[Source: CakePHP Cookbook section on "SQL Injection Prevention"](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#sql-injection-prevention)

Comment: Passing user data into the `key` side of a `key => value` conditions array is unsafe too. In fact, the `key` side is vulnerable in pretty much all places where `key => value` sets are being accepted.

Comment: I havn't thought about it in that way, but that's a really good way to put it @ndm !

Answer (score 1):

CakePHP already comes with SQL injection prevention if you are using the default ORM provided by them:

> CakePHP comes with built-in tools for input validation, CSRF protection, Form tampering protection, SQL injection prevention, and XSS prevention, helping you keep your application safe & secure..

Source: [CakePHP.org](https://cakephp.org)